# undefined symbol error when loading custom ops in tensorflow

Tags: c++, tensorflow, zlib, undefined-symbol

I met a problem when I using `tf.load_op_library('readmat.so')`, where `readmat.so` is my custom C++ code. But I got the following error:

```
gslin@scse-gpu2:~/my_files/CRNN$ python ctpn_cl_icdar15_ch2_train_v1_7.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ctpn_cl_icdar15_ch2_train_v1_7.py", line 13, in <module>
    import ICDAR15_ch2_768x768 as icdar15
  File "./datasets/ICDAR15_ch2_768x768.py", line 15, in <module>
    readmat = tf.load_op_library('/export/home/gslin/my_files/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/readmat.so')
  File "/export/home/gslin/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 64, in load_op_library
    None, None, error_msg, error_code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /export/home/gslin/my_files/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/readmat.so: undefined symbol: inflateInit_
```

The symbol `inflateInit_` is defined in `/usr/include/zlib.h`, which is inclued in readmat.cc.

PS: The error occured after a system upgrade 1 week ago by the adminstrator of this server. I am not the root user.

System: Ubuntu 14.04
Tensorflow: r1.1

Any idea about this problem?

Comment: i guess readmat.so didn't linked with libz.so. check dependencies by run `ldd  readmat.so` and check if you see the libz.so.

Answer (score 0):

@SHD. I am Zichuan Liu, using another account to contact you. I have tested the program on another machine with the same OS and tensorflow. I used `ldd` command to check the dependency and got:

```
tensor_v1@cool-Precision-WorkStation-T7500:~$ ldd ~/tools/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/readmat.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffeda9b4000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd1526fb000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd1523e9000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd15201f000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055bb007c5000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd151e08000)
```

On the machine where I met the problem, I got even the same result when using `ldd`:

```
gslin@scse-gpu2:~/my_files/tensorflow$ ldd bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/user_ops/readmat.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc2769d000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1fa168e000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1fa137c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1fa0fb6000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055c72d6af000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1fa0da0000)
```

But the former one work correctly.